# Colab file errors

Tags: data, colab, analysis

and thank you to whoever answers this. I'm pretty new to data science and machine learning, and I've been trying to immerse myself in it. I feel like there's so much to learn. One of the things that's been a constant frustration: I keep getting the same error over and over again. Whether it's in VS Code or Colab or any platform, when I try to read any sort of file, esp csv files, I get "no such file or directory". I've tried many different things, usually recommended by chatGPT, but no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions? I really want to improve at reading datasets and csv files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Additional details are needed regarding the currently open folder in your VS Code or Colab setup. However, in a general context, resolving this error may involve opening the current directory and providing a relative OR giving the absolute path to your CSV files.
In VS code, you can see your current active directory when you launch the terminal: [image: Current active directory]
If you are running the code in a notebook, the current directory would be the folder in which the notebook is present.